# Yocto meta-toolchain fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, yocto

**Question**: How to add the standard library to arm-fslc-linux-gnueabi-gcc

**Background**: 
I just had bitbake compile the `meta-toolchain` in the Yocto project.
I then installed the resulting SDK-toolchain

> $
>   ./build/tmp/deploy/sdk/fslc-framebuffer-glibc-x86_64-meta-toolchain-armv7at2hf-neon-toolchain-2.4.2.sh

which then installed the SDK-toolchain in /opt/fslc-framebuffer/2.4.2/

I can then easily run the executable to source the correct environment variables.

> $
>   ./opt/fslc-framebuffer/2.4.2/environment-setup-armv7at2hf-neon-fslc-linux-gnueabi

I now have access to the cross-compiler arm-fslc-linux-gnueabi-gcc

**So far so good...**

I then downloaded the barebone SDK from NXP [here](https://community.nxp.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/995668-1-423967/iMX6_Platform_SDK.zip).
It's a great piece of work, but it might be somewhat outdated. First unzip the file, and then follow steps within the SDK readme.pdf.

Following the readme.pdf i do the following: To build the SDK, use the ./tools/build_sdk command from the root folder. I get multiple error but they are all related to the standard library such as:

```
iMX6_Platform_SDK/sdk/drivers/accelerometer/src/mma8451.c:31:10: fatal error: string.h: No such file or directory #include <string.h> 
iMX6_Platform_SDK/sdk/include/sdk.h:40:10: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory #include <stdio.h>
```

**So how do I solve this**? Do I cross compile the standard library or do I get the binary some other place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SDK build by yocto is little bit different than normal arm toolchain.
I believe you used
 `arm-fslc-linux-gnueabi-gcc hello.c`
but actually you need to use `Makefiles or Macros` like below,

```
${CC} hello.c -o hello
```

Write this directly into your terminal or put it into a makefile.

Comment: That works directly in the terminal. Why is this including the correct library? I just echoed: $ echo $CC  Result : "arm-fslc-linux-gnueabi-gcc -march=armv7-a -mthumb -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard --sysroot=/opt/fslc-framebuffer/2.4.2/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-fslc-linux-gnueabi"

Comment: actually this SDK is built by openembedded , also yocto uses macros  to compile the sources(any) when you give the arm-liux-..gcc it doesnt know how where the libs and headers.